# Magento 1.9.1 admin 404 not found

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made a migration of my e-commerce magento site 1.9.1
Since I cannot access the admin as I used to.

Before admin url was www.mydomaine.com/admin. Now that gives an error 404 not found.

To reach admin I have to hit the URL: www.mydomaine.com/index.php/admin

Can someone help me to fix it as it was before.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

### Edit

So indeed I was missing the `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.sample`.
Could not explain why they got cleared but they were not present.

So I imported them.

Now I get the following error: This page has a redirect loop.
And I cannot access neither front or back end :(

So my side is offline....

Below I changed domain name by example.

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path='web/unsecure/base_url';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                   |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|         9 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | http://www.example.com/ |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path='web/secure/base_url';
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                | value                   |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------+-------------------------+
|        10 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url | http://www.example.com/ |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path='web/url/redirect_to_base';
+-----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                     | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
|        73 | default |        0 | web/url/redirect_to_base | 1     |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+-------+
```

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path='web/seo/use_rewrites';
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                 | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
|        74 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I obviously run: `rm -rf var/cache/*` and `rm -rf var/session/*`
I also restarted apache....

Any success.

Comment: Either you've lost your `.htaccess` file, corrupted it or `Redirect` has been disabled on your server.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me where is supposed to be placd in the hierarchie the .htaccess cause I am not able to see it. About Redirect I did that action without success on my server: sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: You should see it in your public folder

Comment: Please check my answer it explain how to solve your issue.

Comment: But now I cannot access any page so I cannot do what is told in your post as he asks to connect to admin pages.

Comment: I tried to re-clear the .htaccess but nothing make the site to work again.I re-install the full site from a back up. I swapped the data base. I reboot the server, apache... disable apache module rewrite.... tried everything. Site off still because of redirection. It's weird. And I get crazy about.

Comment: Okay I found the matter. The DNS config was set up on an incorrect IP since few hour and that was the reason. Nothing link with the fact I upload the .htaccess. Just it happens at the same time. Now with .htaccess i correctly hit admin with the URL www.mydomaine.com/admin

THANKS TO ALL FOR YOUR PRECIOUS HELP.

Answer (score 1):

Better than a copy / paster here you can find the way to remove `index.php` from your URLs. You have to enable URL rewrite in Magento and your server.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504981/3531064